# Looping over list elements without for loop

Tags: python

I have a Python dictionary with multiple values stored as a list like this-

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [2, 3, 4], 'c': [3, 4, 5]}
```

I wish to create a dictionary of lists where each values becomes a key and stores the list as a value like this

```
if __name__=='__main__':
 x={'a':[1,2,3],'b':[2,3,4],'c':[3,4,5]}
 d=dict()
 for key,value in x.items():
   for i in value:
    if i not in list(d.keys()):
     d[i]=value
    else:
     d[i].extend(value)
 print(d)
```

I get the following output-

```
{1: [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4], 2: [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4], 3: [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4], 4: [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4], 5: [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]}
```

I wish for the output to be like this-

```
{1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3], 3: [2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3], 4: [2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5], 5: [3, 4, 5]}
```

1. Where is the error in my code?
2. I wish to avoid nested `for` loops as I have to iterate over a large number of values (`x` dictionary keys and list elements). Is there a better way to iterate over each list value without using nested loops? Should I redo the way I've stored the values (some other data type besides dictionary of lists)?

I'm looking for a solution that is computationally inexpensive in terms of time and maybe space too.

Edit:

By making a copy of the list, the code returns correct output-

```
if __name__=='__main__':
 x={'a':[1,2,3],'b':[2,3,4],'c':[3,4,5]}
 d=dict()
 for key,value in x.items():
  for i in value:
   if i not in list(d.keys()):
    d[i]=list(value)
   else:
    d[i].extend(value)
 print(d)
```

Comment: You need to make a copy of the list: `di = list(value)` otherwise you're extending the same list for different keys.

Comment: Yes. You're right.

Comment: True, but that's not going to be good enough since there are duplicate items in the different lists, so even if you'll copy you'll still get things like: `[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

x={'a':[1,2,3],'b':[2,3,4],'c':[3,4,5]}

d=defaultdict(list)

for key,value in x.items():
    for i in value:
        d[i] += value
```

Or

```
for value in x.values():
    for i in value:
        d[i] += value
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid two `for` loops

Comment: @Misha I don't think so. You'd have to explain more about your structure and what you want to do. There might be other ways.